# Starcraft 2: Rally point for Queen

Tags: starcraft-2

Zerg-ians,

How can I assign a rally point for a Queen (i.e., after it's built out of a Zerg hatchery/lair/hive)?

At the moment, it will simply sit right next to the hatchery(/lair/hive) from which it was created.  In other words, it obeys neither the drone rally point nor the non-drone rally point.

Comment: I don't think you can at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Starcraft Wikia](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Queen_%28StarCraft_II%29):

> You cannot set a rally point for your queen, they always spawn directly next to the hatchery in available space.

Comment: That is a bummer.  Thanks for the quick response (and for citing your source).